# How to call storedprocedure from asp.net MVC controller, using ADO.net without using LinqToSQL or LinqEntities

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wrote a storedprocedure like "PersonDetails" to get Records from multiple tables and filter records. I want call the procedure from controler.

Only with ADO.NET entity framework and should not use Linq language.

Answer (score 1):

You'd call this procedure The same way you would call a stored procedure using ADO.NET in any other application. There is nothing special in MVC that prevents one from doing this.